# Writing into nested Dictionary in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can I not write values into my nested dictionary directly?

It would be nice if I could access it like this:

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>> planets = 
   new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>>();

planets[Planet.CharacterId]["MetalMine"]["Level"] = 0;
```

But I'm getting:

> KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Does this mean I got to insert my `Keys` after each other?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does this mean I got to insert my Keys after each other?

Yes, you need to initialize each in order:

```
planets[Planet.CharacterId] = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
planets[Planet.CharacterId]["MetalMine"] = new Dictionary<string, int>();
planets[Planet.CharacterId]["MetalMine"]["Level"] = 0;
```

You could use collection initializer syntax here, but that won't make stuff much more readable nor maintainable.

Instead of a dictionary of dicionaries of dictionaries you seem to be better off using a class:

```
public class Planet
{
    public List<Mine> Mines { get; set; }
}

public class Mine
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
}

var planets = new Dictionary<string, Planet>();

planets[Planet.CharacterId] = new Planet
{
    Mines = new List<Mine>
    {
        new Mine
        {
            Type = "Metal",
            Level = 0
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i can't accept the answer yet. Will do after the timer runs out.

Answer (score 0):

### It's may be helpful or Nested dictionary alternative.

Create Sample.cs script and test it.

```
 public Dictionary<string,Tuple<string,string,string,int>> _planets = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string,string, string, int>>();
void Start()
    {
       
       string myKey = string.Concat("1","MetalMine","Level");
       if(!_planets.ContainsKey(myKey))
       {
           _planets.Add(myKey,Tuple.Create("1","MetalMine","Level",0));
       }
       Debug.Log("_planets mykey "+myKey+" ==> "+_planets[myKey].Item4);
    }
```